# When to use auto_increment?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I wonder when to use auto_increment. It is said that it can be used for a unique identifier. But why the unique identifier is needed?

Suppose the data of a student has entered in a student table. If I  enter that student data again, it will be ok since it create another id automatically. But I have storing the same data unnecessarily.

What is the meaning of using that?

If I can identify a primary key, I do not need to use that?
For example, For a Hotel table, I can use the combination of Hotel name and address as a primary key. Then, we can avoid storing the same data several times.

Is it better to use to generate a key with auto_increment?

Comment: I suggest you Google normalisation and think about why it would be a bad (very bad) idea to store the same data twice (maintainance? which version is correct/definitive?)

Comment: As @Colin 't Hart suggests, please put your question about using "Hotel name and address as a primary key" in the question about. As to using these as a PK, there can be performance issues with long keys (esp. in MySQL) - and anyway, hotels **often** change names - and (more rarely) street names and even cities can be renamed (Think St. Petersburg, Petrograd, Leningrad, St. Petersburg or Chemnitz, Karl Marx Stadt... &c.).

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of using an auto increment field is that new records are automatically given an unique primary key.

> Suppose the data of a student has entered in a student table. If I enter that student data again, it will be ok since it create another id automatically. But I have storing the same data unnecessarily.

It's your duty to take care that the same data is not entered again i.e. verify that the student exists and, if yes, edit his record instead of creating a new one.

> If I can identify a primary key, I do not need to use that?

Yes, if you can identify a **natural primary key** (e.g. the student ID in an University, the ISBN for a book, the S/N for a piece of hardware) it is much better to use that one.

> For example, For a Hotel table, I can use the combination of Hotel name and address as a primary key.

It is a bad idea to use primary keys which contain meaningful data. What happens if the hotel changes its name? In this example, it is better to use a surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot identify a primary key for a table you need to use [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key); auto_increment columns are most common surrogate keys which database internally provides and hence you should use them then.
You may alternatively have sequences or programmatically handle uniqueness...

Comment: "programmatically handle uniqueness" - bad idea. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: well I agree...